# How do I get the created date of a json file using ajax/javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I need to be able to find out what the creation date of a json file is using javascript or ajax.

Is this even possible??

My code below requests the json file but im an unsure of how I tell when it was created.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',                   
    url:  localLiveUrl+'/api/v1/productchoice.json?website='+website,
    async: true,
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(productchoice){ 
    }
});
```

Comment: "using javascript or ajax" — JavaScript is a programming language. Ajax is something you can do with JavaScript. It never makes sense to choose between them.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to the jQuery Ajax success handler is a `jqXHR` object, which includes a `getResponseHeader` method. You can use this to inspect the `Last-Modified` HTTP header.

```
function handler(data, status, xhr) {
   alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified'));
}

$.ajax('/', {
  success: handler,
});
```

Caveats:

- You can only use this when using XHR. There is no way to access the headers when using JSON-P.
- This only works if the server supplies a Last-Modified response header
- This assumes that the Last-Modified response header the server sends is trustworthy

Answer (score 0):

With **JS**, you could simple create a `Date` object inside the success function:

```
    ...
    success: function(productchoice){ 
        var date = new Date();
        data = date.valueOf();
    }
});
```

Or, if possible, you could add the date when the file was generated or requested inside your JSON file.